Merging customized system workflow message templates
I have some customized system workflow message templates and I've upgraded Civi. The upgrade process alerted me that I need to do a merge. The instructions for doing the merge indicate (in step 2) that I should "see which templates CiviCRM has changed", but it doesn't tell me how. In later steps, the CRM/Upgrade directory is indicated, but I'm not sure which file(s) I should be looking at in that directory. I don't see any files there that seem to contain copies of these templates.
I fell back to using the admin interface and clicking "View Default" to see the upgraded versions of the templates, but, as the instructions say (in step 4), I would like to find the previous default versions of the templates to do a 3-way merge.
Is the documentation incomplete in step 2?
What's the recommended way to do this merge?

This doesn't address your point about the previous default, but it has some nice features including being able to preview what would be sent out, using the new code, and based on your last 25 receipts etc https://civicrm.org/extensions/better-message-templates
